# Pedir permisos en Android

Tags: java, android, permisos

Estoy realizando una tarea de pedir permisos a una aplicación. Este es el código:

```
    private static String TAG = "xxxxxx";
    private static final int RQC = 1;
    private String[] grupoPermisos = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        compruebaPermiso();
    }

    private void compruebaPermiso() {
        for (String cad: grupoPermisos){
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,cad) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{cad}, RQC);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

El problema es que no me pide más de un permiso y si hago un grupo de permisos y se lo pido todo en un array, solo me pide dos de esos tres permisos. También me dice que no hace falta comprobar la versión de Android, aunque estoy en API 26.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Gracias.

Comment: Pues, muestra el código de tu array para ver cómo lo haces.

Comment: Ese es todo el código, no comprendo a que te refieres

Comment: Pues el problema que estas teniendo es que estas diciéndole a tu  **RQC** que su valor es **1**. Tu `array` tiene tres valores, esos valores van del **0 al 0 (0,1,2)** por lo que cuando declaras `requestPermissions(new String[]{cad}, RQC);` va a tomar el elemento tenga por posición **1** de tu `array` y ese elemento es `Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG`

Comment: Pero ese valor tiene que ser una constante, o cuando es un grupo, puedo utilizar un entero que incremente el valor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es **importante que los permisos se encuentren definidos también dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`** de otra forma no podrá mostrarse la ventana para aceptar permisos.

En cuanto a tu código, usa el contexto de tu Activity para requerir el servicio.

```
private void compruebaPermiso() {
    for (String cad: grupoPermisos){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,cad) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                //requestPermissions(new String[]{cad}, RQC);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( 
            MainActivity.this, 
            new String[] {cad}, 
            RQC);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a intentar seguir con tu modificación.